# customise text box in zend

Tags: php, html, css, zend-framework

```
              My expected output is this
```

https://s9.postimg.org/v85i5gm73/required_output.png
but i am getting output as
https://s1.postimg.org/k6vx1h5nj/wrong_output.png
I am using zend framework.
my form is

```
    $this->setMethod('post');
    $username = $this->createElement('text','username');
    $username->setLabel('Username')
    ;
    $username->setAttrib("class"," member_login");
    $password = $this->createElement('password','password');
    $password->setLabel('password:')

    $password->setAttrib("class","member_login");
```

My view code is

```
<?php echo $this->form; ?>
```

and css is

```
   .member_login{
    width: 635px;
    float:left; 
    padding-left:30px;
}

   .member_login input{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #999;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 5px 10px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Did you check your generated HTML output?